# Recording a group of people

Tags: microphone, recording, studio

I am going to be recording a group of six people, who will be in two rows (three people in front, three behind them), facing a camera. This is for a marathon livestream in which the people will swapping out consistently, and the mics will be in use for in excess of five days. We are looking for the best option to get good audio from these people while keeping the following in mind:

- We cannot use lavaliers, as the group of people will be switching out throughout the event.
- Microphones should have an option for phantom power, as switching batteries during the event would not be ideal.
- We will be indoors, the room will not have much echo due to padded walls and carpeted floors.
- We are on a budget, but not strict. We can likely spend around $1000 safely, but would prefer less.

Our current plans involve buying two Rode NTG2s, and mounting them high, pointed down at the two rows.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you are asking here.  It seems that you basically understand what you need to do and have a really low price cap that prevents much in the way of options beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

its Elaborinth8993.

What I am suggesting might not be what you are looking for, but it would produce the best sound quality for what you need.

I may be going over the top with what I think you need, but it can be easily scaled back to fit what you actually need.

First thing you would need that I do not know you own is a mixing board. something like this http://www.fullcompass.com/product/382185.html

If you already have one, Awesome! that saves you a bunch of money. but if you don't I would suggest you get one because it gives you more control over sound then just "set it and forget it"

Now on to the actual response of "What do i do for audio?"

I have done research, and this group of stuff i am suggesting can be bought for a total of around $800 but can be easily brought down to around $600.

Here is the $800 equipment list.

2 of these:

Sennheiser THREEPACK 
3 E835 Microphones w/3 Carrying Pouches and clips
$249.95 on FullCompass

6 of these:

On-Stage Stands DS7200B
9"-13" H Desktop Microphone Stand
$12.95 on FullCompass

And 6 of these if you want pop filters:

Audix PD-133
Pop Diffuser
$28.95 on Full Compass

Now I do not know if Microphones on a table is the look you are going for. because that can get distracting to look at, but it will look like any PAX or ComiCon panel you have seen, and it will sound the best. no echo because everyone has their own mic and not a group of people talking into 1 mic. and no background stuff picked up by the 2 overhead mics

This group of stuff can be scaled back to $600.

Buy 1 of these:

Sennheiser THREEPACK 
3 E835 Microphones w/3 Carrying Pouches and clips
$249.95 on FullCompass

1 of these:

Sennheiser e835
Evolution Series Cardioid Vocal Microphone
$99.99 on Full Compass

4 of these:

On-Stage Stands DS7200B
9"-13" H Desktop Microphone Stand
$12.95 on FullCompass

and 4 of these if you want pop filters:

Audix PD-133
Pop Diffuser
$28.95 on Full Compass

This would be 2 mics on each table. 1 person with their own mic, and 2 people sharing a mic. which could work (First table is the person playing the game and his co-runner, 2nd table is 3 people commentating)

I hope this helps you MC, if you still want the hidden Microphone set-up, than the plan you have now, would probably be the best. the Rode NTG's are good mics and getting them above people would not be too hard.

What I am suggesting would just be a better audio set-up. because I would be worried about those Rode's picking up a conversation across the room.

Have a good day,

Elaborinth8993

and sorry for the formatting. I am only allowed 2 links, so I had to reformat this whole thing.

Also, what ever plan you go with, you will need audio cable. 30ft is $13 a piece which should be long enough

(WARNING: I am in no way an audio expert, I am a lighting guy for theatre, I only set-up and plug in mics on occasion, I do not operate or know the difference between mic brands. But that being said, I work with a professional sound guy and this is the set-up he would use in a situation like this.)

Comment: The reason for direct micing with a panel is that the crowd will be making noise as well and amplification is being used, so feedback is a concern.  For video recording in a quiet environment, recording to fewer mics can actually produce more natural sound since it captures the relative levels of everyone talking and is certainly cheaper.  The visual look also needs to be considered.  Additionally, if they don't have a mixer, this will completely blow their budget.  I wouldn't say it isn't a solution, but I wouldn't call this an ideal one for their scenario as it is currently explained.